# Cannot show two dim normal distribution contour by using mvtnorm library

Tags: r

I failed to show the contour of this distribution in the following codes.

```
grid <- seq(-1,1,0.01)
mu_prior <- rep(0, 2)
alpha <- 0.5
sigma_prior <- alpha * diag(2)

library(mvtnorm)
f <- function(x,y){return(dmvnorm(c(x,y), mu_prior, sigma_prior))}

z <- outer(grid, grid, f)
contour(grid, grid, z)
```

The error shows

> Error in dmvnorm(z, mu_prior, sigma_prior) : 
>     mean and sigma have non-conforming size

I cannot understand it because the column size of mu_prior is the same as that of sigma_prior.
For Example, the following code is successfully executed

```
dmvnorm(c(0,0), mu_prior, sigma_prior)
```

> [1] 0.07957747

Could you tel me where I should correct?

Comment: Try `cbind(x,y)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the R document of `outer()`, the argument `FUN` is restricted to be **vectorized**. In short, the binary function you call in `outer()` need to satisfy **many-to-one** property, that is, `FUN(c(-1, 0, 1), 0)` should be executable. Your function:

```
f <- function(x,y){return(dmvnorm(c(x, y), mu_prior, sigma_prior))}
```

is unable to deal with `f(c(-1, 0, 1), 0)`. There are two methods to make it vectorized:

**(1) `cbind()`**

```
f1 <- function(x,y){return(dmvnorm(cbind(x, y), mu_prior, sigma_prior))}
z1 <- outer(grid, grid, f1)
contour(grid, grid, z1)
```

**(2) `Vectorize()`**

```
f2 <- Vectorize(f)              # It's slower than the former.
z2 <- outer(grid, grid, f2)
contour(grid, grid, z2)
```

[image]